# Creating error/result function in node

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm having trouble understanding how to create functions that would return in the format of `(err, result)` for an Express app.

My current db query function is:

```
pool.query(
  'SELECT id FROM users WHERE email = ? LIMIT 1',
  [email],
  (results) => { // I'd like this to be (err, results)
    if(results instanceof Error){...}
  }
})
```

In my db.js file, pool looks like this:

```
module.exports = {
  query: (query, args, cb) => {
    pool.getConnection( (err, connection) => {
      if(err){
        new Error('No database connections available in pool')
      } else {
        connection.query(query, args, (error, results, fields) => {
          connection.release()
          // I got a MySQL error here and I'd like to handle it in my callback function
          if(error){
            new Error('Bad query')
          } else {
            cb(results)
          }
        })
      }
    })
  }
}
```

For this and other functions, I'd like to return a proper `Error` if there is one, and have my callback listen for `err, result` as parameters.

I tried using `new Error('Bad query')` but that came back as the first variable in my callback no matter what (which is how I ended up with `instanceof Error`.

How do you structure a callback and response so that your callback can be in the `err, result` format and check for/handle errors properly *on functions you're creating*? (I understand how to use it for modules already in this format - I'm talking about writing/formatting your own code.)

Thanks!

Comment: Please show us the rest of your code for your query function.  The place to fix your issue is where it calls the `cb()`.  That's where you pass `err` as the first argument and `results` as the second argument.  If you show us the rest of that function's code, we can show you how to do the callback properly in it.

Comment: Thanks @jfriend00 - I just added the rest of the query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
module.exports = {
  query: (query, args, cb) => {
    pool.getConnection( (err, connection) => {
      if(err){
        cb(new Error('No database connections available in pool'));
      } else {
        connection.query(query, args, (error, results, fields) => {
          connection.release();
          // I got a MySQL error here and I'd like to handle it in my callback function
          if(error){
            cb(new Error('Bad query'));
          } else {
            cb(null, results);
          }
        });
      }
    });
  }
}
```

You always pass the error value as the first argument to the callback and, if there is a result, you pass it as the second.  Then, within the callback, you check to see if `err` is non-null and, if so, there is an error.  If it's `null`, then the second argument contains the result.

Note that by not returning or including the actual `err` value that the database gave you, you may be hiding useful information (like why the query failed).

---

Then, where you use this, you do something like this:

```
let query = 'SELECT id FROM users WHERE email = ? LIMIT 1'; 
pool.query(query, [email], (err, result) => {
    if (err) {
        // handle error here
    } else {
        // process result here
    }
});
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was missing. Thanks!

Comment: @Joe-NewNine - I added an example of how you call it and use the callback.